# How to draw a graph without edges that intersect in jgraphx?

Tags: jgraphx

I want to draw a graph that doesn't have edges that intersect, but when I create an edge (e1) from vertex (v1) to vertex (v2) and another edge (e2) from v2 to v1, a double arrow appears. How do I separate e1 and e2 in two different edges?

I also want to avoid that the edges intersect with vertexes or that vertexes intersect with others vertexes.

How do I draw a graph without edges and vertexes that intersect?

Answer (score 0):

You can run the mxParrallelEdgeLayout after you added the second Edge.
Sth like this:

```
new mxParallelEdgeLayout(yourGraph).execute(yourGraph.getDefaultParent());
```

Comment: with mxParallelEdgeLayout  if I create a edge (e1) from vertex (v1) to vertex (v1) and another edge (e2) from v1 to v1;  e1 and e2 intersect too

Comment: I also want to avoid that the edges intersect with vertexes but with mxParallelEdgeLayout it continues happening...

Comment: Hmm, you could try the different layouts JGraphX supports. However I don't think it is supported out of the box. Of course there are graphs that are impossible to draw without intersecting edges...

Comment: well, which is the best layout to draw finite automatons with JGraphX?

Comment: Honestly, I have no Idea. You could try mxHierarchicalLayout, but it fails if your graph contains too many circles. I myself prefer mxFastOrganicLayout with a custom forceConstant, and afterwards I execute a mxParallelEdgeLayout to avoid overlapping edges.